# Difference admin save and cli script save?

Tags: magento2

**Background**: Some products option detail (e.g. text field data) is not correctly held through the process... User enters data on the product page and it is missing in the basket page.  A simple fix is to save the product in the admin (no changes)... so am building a script to save all products with product options.

**Problem**: The script isn't fixing the problem, so it is not performing the same actions as the admin save with the GUI.  Why?

Here is my script:

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$instance = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

$arrProductIDs = [...];

foreach ($arrProductIDs as $iProductID) {
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($iProductID);
    $product->save();
    echo $iProductID.' saved - ';
}
```

I have also tried changing some data a little, but no better:

```
$desc_orig = $product->getDescription();
$product->setDescription($desc_orig.' ');
```

Can anyone please help me understand fix this so that I can replicate going into the admin and saving all of these products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of service contracts, as the `load()` and `save()` methods are officially deprecated.

Use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` or even better `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` to load and save products.

```
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
foreach ($arrProductIDs as $iProductID) {
    $product = $productRepository->getById($iProductID);
    $productRepository->save($product);
    echo $iProductID.'-';
}
```

If you're still having problems, it would maybe help to get more informations. Also, you might want to look into the product's saving process. IIRC, the admin *always* saves new custom options in some Magento versions, while this isn't necessarily done when simply running a script.

Comment: `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` didn't work, but I've updated to use `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` which does work, thank you!